# Type checking in variable-length argument lists

Tags: java

I need to create a TreeNode class, that will be able to store **childs of two types**: String and TreeNode. **Number of childs is not fixed.**

I want to create TreeNode objects somehow like this:

```
TreeNode a = new TreeNode("str", new TreeNode("str2"), "str3"); //Correct
TreeNode b = new TreeNode(a, "str4); //Correct
TreeNode c = new TreeNode(54); //Wrong
```

How can I do arguments **type checking** with wildcards or something else in **compile time**?

My inappropriate runtime solution:

```
private static final boolean debug = "true".equals(System.getProperty("debug"));

public <T> TreeNode (T... childs) {
    if (debug) {
        for (Object child : childs) {
            if (!(child instanceof String || child instanceof TreeNode)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Type of childs must me Tree or String");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really not sane use of generics at all. `TreeNode` instances can have heterogeneous children with no upper bound?

Comment: Compile time checking and generics can't help you. What should `TreeNode#get()` return?

Comment: TreeNode.get() return a string, which is a contatination of child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters in constructor should have special meaning. Using varargs there is acceptable but it think that those are special cases. And you problem can be solved in another way.

```
public class TreeNode {

   public TreeNode() {
     //crate the object
   }

   public TreeNode addNode(String node, String... nodes) {
    //Do something with string node
    return this;
   }

   public TreeNode addNode(TreeNode node, TreeNode... nodes) {
   //Do something with TreeNode
    return this;
   }
}
```

So you could use this like this for example

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode().addNode("One","Two").addNode(node3,node4);
```

where node3 and node4 are instaces of TreeNode;

Answer (score 2):

You should try to find a single base type which you can add to your tree. Then, derive your concrete node types from it:

```
abstract class Node { }
class TreeNode extends Node {
  public TreeNode(Node... children) {
    // ...
  }
}
class StringNode extends Node { 
  public StringNode(String value) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
TreeNode a = new TreeNode(
  new StringNode("str"), 
  new TreeNode(new StringNode("str2")), 
  new StringNode("str3"));
```

Comment: Can I implicitly cast String to StringNode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public <T> TreeNode (Object... childs) {
  //code
}
```

Comment: TreeNode c = new TreeNode(54); Should not be compiled

Comment: How does this disallow `54` at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still graft some degree of compile-time typesafety, you can do this:

```
public class AorB<A, B> {
  private final Object _instance;
  private final boolean _isA;

  public AorB(A instance) {
    _instance = instance;
    _isA = true;
  }

  public AorB(B instance) {
    _instance = instance;
    _isA = false;
  }

  public A asA() {
    assert _isA;
    return (A) _instance;
  }

  public B asB() {
    assert !_isA;
    return (B) _instance;
  }

  public boolean isA() {
    return _isA;
  }
}
```

And then use `AorB<String, TreeNode>` instances.

Note that you can go even further and also have a typesafe callback, if you don't like that someone might do `asB()` when the instance is an `A`:

```
public class AorB<A, B> {
  ...
  public interface Handler<A, B> {
    void handle(A instnace);
    void handle(B instance);
  }

  public void handle(Handler<A, B> handler) {
    if (isA()) {
      handler.handle(asA());
    } else {
      handler.handle(asB());
    }
  }
```